# Suppose $a_n$ approaches $a$ as $n$ approaches $\infty$. Let $b_n$ = $\sum_{i=1}^n {((-1)^{i-1})(a_i)\over n}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Prove that $b_n$ approaches $0$ as $n$ approaches $\infty$ .

How would I go about proving this? I can visualize and understand why it works but don't know how to show it.

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n >N$ then $b_n= \frac  1 n\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} (-1)^{i-1} a_i+ \frac  1 n\sum\limits_{i=N+1}^{n} (-1)^{i-1} a_i$. In the second term  group the terms two by two and note that we get differences $a_j -a_{j-1}$ and we can choose $N$ such that all these differences are less than $\epsilon$. This gives $|\frac  1 n\sum\limits_{i=N+1}^{n} (-1)^{i-1} a_i| \leq  \epsilon (\frac {n-N} {2n}+1)<\frac 3  2\epsilon$. Now note that the first term tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: what's relevant is that the absolute values of the differences are bounded by $\epsilon$